# Wrap comma separated names from string in span elements

Tags: php, explode

I'm having a string contains names comma separated:

```
Rudi Mentar, Max Muster, Lorem Ipsum, Vorname Nachname
```

I need to wrap every name into a span with class name "nowrap". Desired result:

```
<span class="nowrap">Rudi Mentar,</span><span class="nowrap">Max Muster,</span><span class="nowrap">Lorem Ipsum,</span><span class="nowrap">Vorname Nachname</span>
```

Any idea?

Comment: `explode` has a counterpart `implode`, and I am assuming you know how basic string concatenation works - so, what more do you need?

Comment: maybe i'm wrong with explode, was thinking this is the right direction, but i don't know how to do.

Comment: explode is half of it, the other half is implode. _“but i don't know how to do”_ - don’t know how to do what, _exactly_? The steps that need to happen here, is that you split your string into an array of values, and then “glue” the elements of that array together again, but using a different separator in between than what was there before. Now what exactly about that is giving your trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did that way:

```
$names_array = explode(',' , $names);
foreach( $names_array as $key => $sss ){
    echo "<span class='nowrap'>{$sss}</span>";
    echo ( ( $key < ( count( $names_array ) -1 ) ) ? ', ':'' );
}
```